# What will happen if Dropbox can't create a conflicted copy of a big file because of luck of Dropbox storage space?

Tags: dropbox

I use it to sync truecrypt drive files. There are 2 or 3 files that take almost all storage space. What if I change them on my notebook while they are still opened on my home pc?

Comment: If DropBox on your home PC can't update the local copy of the file because it is in use, it will wait until they are closed before syncing the PC... Eventually the newest copy of the file will be on both machines. It is likely that changes made by one of your machines will be lost.

Comment: I thought that dropbox acted like this in its early stages, but recently it recognizes different versions of files (at least with .doc files). If there are different versions of files, dropbox will try to save both files. But if there's not enough space, a client will remain with an error that it cannot upload due to space restrictions.